# how to perform parameter mapping in api gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to remove and add new parameter in proxy integration in aws api gatway so that incoming parameter is removed and new one added based on the removed parameter. Basically I am renaming parameter in following way

`id -> fields.id`

In parameter mapping section (although I would like to do this in SAM template later) I am doing following

| Parameter to modify | Modification type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| querystring.fields.id | Append | $request.querystring.id |
| querystring.id | Remove |  |

I get invalid mapping expression specified for "fields.id" because it does not match regular expression allowed in console. But using SAM template it works. But then in SAM template removing does not work (at least I don't know what correct syntax it). This is what I tried in SAM template

```
      RequestParameters:
        append:querystring.fields.id: '$request.querystring.id'
        remove:$request.querystring.pzId
```

And using template "remove" fails.

So using SAM and then console I managed to strong arm it into accepting append and remove. But when testing call I get message from endpoint

```
{"sys":{"type":"Error","id":"InvalidQuery"},"message":"The query you sent was invalid. Probably a filter or ordering specification is not applicable to the type of a field.","details":{"errors":[{"name":"type","path":["fields"],"type":"Object","filter":"equals","details":"The equals operator cannot be used on fields because it has type Object."}]},"requestId":"2a03f13b-ed1a-4a3f-a639-1099bcd4038e"}
```

So AWS is doing something that it should not with that parameter and I have no idea how to make this work. Manually crafted url against same endpoint works fine.

Any ideas how to make this work?